# Line up generated divs horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a map generator that lets a user enter the number of rows and columns in the map, and then create that map (as divs). Everything works correctly, *except* the divs, instead of being in rows and columns, it's all in one big column. It does have the correct amount of tiles (for example, it has 6 if you enter 3 and 2, or 25 if you enter 5 and 5). The kicker is that if I enter divs in the regular html file, they line up like they're supposed to.

Here's my javascript function:

```
 function createMap(rows, columns) {
     var $div = $('<div></div>');
     var k = 0;
     while (k < rows) {
         for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
             $div.append('<div></div>');
         }

     $div.append('<br>');
     k++;
     }
     $('body').empty();
     $('body').append($div);
}
```

Here's my CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The generated divs are reading the CSS fine - they have the proper height, width, and border. It seems that they're just creating a new line for every one. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Try floating the divs to the left

Comment: Show us the HTML or a demo. Floats are not necessary and often cause more problems.

Comment: You are creating unnecessary jQuery objects, which makes your code highly inefficient. You should only work with pure string concatenation and only create one jQuery object at the end, i. e., assuming you have a `grid` string variable containing all your divs, simply do `$('body').replaceWith($('<div></div>').append(grid));`. See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90owd99m/)**

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos I'm still new to javascript/jQuery and am not aware of good/bad practices, so thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave ALL your divs a width of 100px. You have divs in a div. So you need to change your styles to only target the children

You want only the children divs to have the width of 100px.

```js
 function createMap(rows, columns) {
     var $div = $('<div></div>');
     var k = 0;
     while (k < rows) {
         for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
             $div.append('<div></div>');
         }

     $div.append('<br>');
     k++;
     }
     $('body').empty();
     $('body').append($div);
}

createMap(2,3)
```

```css
div > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float your divs

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `inline-block` and floats are redundant.

Comment: Did he really just look at the comments and create an answer based on them? bad karma for you dude!

Comment: @DaveBurns Actually, nope! I thought he was missing `float` but I hadn't read the JS logic seeing it was a CSS issue.

Comment: It is a CSS issue, just not this CSS issue.